# How to sign data using .p12 in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, x509certificate, sign

I have codes to sign data in desktop app.
But it don't work with UWP because I can't use these namespace

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

This is full [source code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=678E939916E85863!493926&authkey=!AAjYhB2makZ8AWw&ithint=file%2Ccs)
Thank you.

Comment: Of course it does not work.  You don't have any actual code.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your quality up

Answer (score 0):

There is a new API in the universal windows platform to perform cryptography.
You will find all you need from the [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx) namespace.